# delete question still showing anyway to completely delete question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

why my deleted answer or question not deleting permanently they are still showing. i want to delete it completely so no body can see it.is there any way to do it or they are permanently or we need this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to *completely* delete a question or answer. They are always visible to yourself and to moderators. It is also not possible to self-delete a question with 3 answers or more.

Comment: what you say on `we need this feature`

Comment: We can't make this decision. We're mods of this particular sub. This is a feature that would be necessary for the entirety of Stackoverflow/Stackexchange and, to answer your question, I don't think we need it, no.